# How to scrape Subcategories and pages in categories of a Category wikipedia page using Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, wikipedia

So I'm trying to scrape all the subcategories and pages under the category header of the Category page: "Category: Class-based programming languages" found at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Class-based_programming_languages

I've figured out a way to do this using urls and the mediawiki API: Categorymembers. The way to do that would be:

- base: `en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Class-based%20programming%20languages&format=json&cmlimit=500`
- base: `en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Class-based%20programming%20languages&format=json&cmlimit=500&cmtype=subcat`

However, I can't find a way to accomplish this using Python. Can anyone help me out here?

This is for independent study and I've spent a lot of time on this, but just can't seem to figure it out. Also, the use of Beautifulsoup is prohibited. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Can you use lxml?

Comment: Yup. No issues there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so after doing more research and study, I was able to find an answer to my own question. Using the libraries `urllib.request` and `json`, I imported the wikipedia url file in format json and simply printed its categories out that way. Here's the code I used to get the subcategories:

```py
pages = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Class-based%20programming%20languages&format=json&cmlimit=500&cmtype=subcat")
data = json.load(pages)
query = data['query']
category = query['categorymembers']
for x in category:
    print (x['title'])
```

And you can do the same thing for pages in category. Thanks to Nemo for trying to help me out!

Comment: @Park. Thanks. But how to extract the contents of all the available pages (say restrict the pages to 1000 for a category)?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from lxml import html
wiki_page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Class based_programming_languages')
tree = html.fromstring(wiki_page.content)
```

To build your intuition of how to use this, right click on, say, 'C++', and click 'inspect' and you'll see the panel in the right will have highlighted

```
<a class="CategoryTreeLabel  CategoryTreeLabelNs14   
CategoryTreeLabelCategory" href="/wiki/Category:C%2B%2B">C++</a>
```

Right click on this, and click 'copy xpath'. For C++ this will give you

```
//*[@id="mw-subcategories"]/div/ul[1]/li/div/div[1]/a
```

Similarly, under the pages, for 'ActionScript' we get

```
//*[@id="mw-pages"]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a
```

So if you're looking for all the subcategory/page names, you could do, for example

```
pages = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-pages"]/text()')
subcategories = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-subcategories"]/text()')
```

[For more information see here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/#web-scraping) and [here](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I am not getting in a clearer way. I am looking into scrape all the subcategories/page names for the category lets say Category:Computer science. The link is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_science`

Comment: There is no such restriction. BeautifulSoup can be used!