# Python scraping of Wikipedia category page

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia

I have this Wikipedia category page: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Pi%C3%A8ce_de_th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre_du_XVIIIe_si%C3%A8cle

I'd like to open the page of each play listed (e.g. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Oiseau_vert) and print the first sentence of it (e.g. *L'Oiseau vert (L'augellino belverde) est une comédie de Carlo Gozzi (auteur italien de pièces de théâtre) parue en 1765*). A dataframe with the play title in the 1st column and the first sentence in the 2nd one would also be good.

I tried to get all the page links through `BeautifulSoup` and print the first sentences with `wikipedia.summary()` but results are not satisfactory, since the `wikipedia` module often redirects to the wrong articles. Part of the problem may be caused by the French special characters within the play titles (é, â, etc.)

Is there a better method to access the individual articles directly from the category page?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495405/how-to-scrape-subcategories-and-pages-in-categories-of-a-category-wikipedia-page) seems related but hasn't helped me further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how you can achieve that using `beautifulsoup` only:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_categories(data):
    print("Getting categories...")
    categories = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
    group_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mw-category-group"})
    for div in group_divs:
        links = div.find_all("a")
        for link in links:
            title = link.get("title")
            href = link.get("href")
            categories[title] = "https://fr.wikipedia.org" + href
    print(f"Found Categories: {len(categories)}")
    return categories


def get_first_paragraph(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
    parser_output = soup.find("div", {"class": "mw-parser-output"})
    first_paragraph = parser_output.find("p", {"class": None}, recursive=False)
    return first_paragraph.text


def process_categories(categories):
    result = {}
    for title, link in categories.items():
        print(f"Processing Piece: {title}, on link: {link}")
        data = requests.get(link).content
        first_paragraph = get_first_paragraph(data)
        result[title] = first_paragraph.strip()
    return result


def clean_categories(categories):
    return {k: v for k, v in categories.items() if "Catégorie" not in k}


def main():
    categories_url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Pi%C3%A8ce_de_th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre_du_XVIIIe_si%C3%A8cle"
    data_categories = requests.get(categories_url).content
    categories = get_categories(data_categories)
    categories = clean_categories(categories)
    result = process_categories(categories)
    print(result) # create dataframe etc...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code is self-explanatory:

- First we find `div`s that have `category-group` class, extract all `a` elements and get `title` and `href`
- Then for each `category` i.e. piece we parse HTML and get the first `p` in the `div` with `mw-parser-output` class (That should be the first sentence).

> Note: I added `clean_categories` since `category-group` picked up unwanted things that had `Catégorie` in them.

Example of output for first couple of pieces:

```
Getting categories...
Found Categories: 198
Processing Piece: Les Acteurs de bonne foi, on link: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Acteurs_de_bonne_foi
Processing Piece: Adamire ou la Statue de l'honneur, on link: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamire_ou_la_Statue_de_l%27honneur
Processing Piece: Agamemnon (Lemercier), on link: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agamemnon_(Lemercier)
Processing Piece: Agathocle (Voltaire), on link: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathocle_(Voltaire)
```

And Result:

```
{"Adamire ou la Statue de l'honneur": "Adamire ou la Statue de l'honneur est "
                                      'la traduction par Thomas-Simon '
                                      'Gueullette de la pièce de théâtre '
                                      "italienne l'Adamira overo la Statua "
                                      "dell'Honore de Giacinto Andrea "
                                      'Cicognini représentée pour la première '
                                      'fois en France le 12 décembre 1717 à '
                                      "Paris, à l'Hôtel de Bourgogne.",
 'Agamemnon (Lemercier)': 'Agamemnon est une tragédie en cinq actes considérée '
                          "comme le chef-d'œuvre dramatique de Népomucène "
                          'Lemercier. Elle fut représentée au Théâtre de la '
                          'République le 5 floréal an V (24 avril 1797) et '
                          'valut à son auteur une célébrité immédiate.',
 'Agathocle (Voltaire)': 'Agathocle est une tragédie écrite par Voltaire, '
                         'représentée pour la première fois le 31 mai 1779, '
                         'sur la scène de la Comédie-Française.',
 'Les Acteurs de bonne foi': 'Les Acteurs de bonne foi est une comédie en un '
                             'acte et en prose de Marivaux, jouée pour la '
                             'première fois chez Quinault cadette le 30 '
                             'octobre 1748.'}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a better method to access the individual articles directly from the category page: Wikipedia API!

You can try this:

```
import requests

url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
params = {
    "action": "query",
    "cmtitle": "Catégorie:Pièce de théâtre du XVIIIe siècle",
    "cmlimit": "50",
    "list": "categorymembers",
    "format": "json"
}
req = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
pages = req.json()['query']['categorymembers']

# here just iterate over category individual pages
for page in pages:
    # eg. page = {'pageid': 622757, 'ns': 0, 'title': 'Les Acteurs de bonne foi'}
    _url = 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
    _params = {
        'format': 'json',
        'action': 'query',
        'prop': 'extracts',
        'exintro': True,
        'explaintext': True,
        'redirects': 1,
        'pageids': page['pageid'],
    }
    req = requests.get(_url, _params)
    summary = req.json()['query']['pages'][str(page['pageid'])]['extract']
```

In case of 'Les Acteurs de bonne foi'  the summary returns:

> 'Les Acteurs de bonne foi est une comédie en un acte et en prose de
> Marivaux, jouée pour la première fois chez Quinault cadette le 30
> octobre 1748.\nMarivaux fit jouer les Acteurs de bonne foi au
> Théâtre-Français en 1755, mais la pièce ne réussit pas. Elle fut
> publiée pour la première fois dans le Conservateur de novembre 1757.
> L’intérêt de la pièce repose principalement sur un jeu qu’entretient
> Marivaux avec son lecteur grâce à la mise en abyme. En effet, le texte
> mêle au sein d’une même page : entretien des acteurs sur leurs vies
> respectives, dialogues sur les possibilités de jeu et de mise en scène
> ainsi que répliques d’un texte qui est alors joué. Dans cette pièce,
> qui est la dernière que l’auteur ait fait jouer sur un grand théâtre,
> où la scène de comédie est rapidement détournée et donne lieu à une
> confusion entre la situation réelle et la scène jouée, la mise en
> abyme révèle l’importance de l’illusion théâtrale.'

Comment: Why not use `params` in the second get request?

Comment: You're right. I edited it for consistency.

Comment: Also you don't have to be using the session and you don't need to import bs4 :)